# Garbage value in http response

Tags: java, android, xml, string, response

im working on android and on getting response from http my xml code contain lots of garbage value at tahe end.. how do i remove that garbage...
please suggest

my xml string with garbage value is

```
<player><id>1</id><name>sachin</name><value>98</value></player>ÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀ
```

here is the code where im creating array and returning its values

```
    private ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> score = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id.add(id);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.add(name);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score.add(score);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value.add(value);
    }
```

and this is the code from where im accessing values :

```
Boolean currentElement = false;
String currentValue = null;
public static ScoreList scorelist = null;

public static ScoreList getScorelist() {
    return scorelist;
}

public static void setScoreList(ScoreList scorelist) {
    XMLHandler.scorelist = scorelist;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

  if (localName.equals("id"))
    {
        /** Start */
        scorelist = new ScoreList();
        }else if (localName.equals("id")) {
        }else if (localName.equals("name")) {
        }else if (localName.equals("score")) {
        }else if (localName.equals("value")) {
    }

    }

        @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("id"))
            scorelist.setId(currentValue);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
            scorelist.setName(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("score"))
            scorelist.setScore(currentValue);
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("value"))
            scorelist.setValue(currentValue);

    }

        @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (currentElement) {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentElement = false;
        }

    }
```

here in my http code i gave the byte length also but still it is giving garbage values.. because of it it is throwing null pointer and string out of bound exception.. my code is

```
                UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps,HTTP.UTF_8);
                httppost.setEntity(p_entity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                Log.v(TAG, response.getStatusLine().toString());
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in=responseEntity.getContent();

                byte[] bData = new byte[1024];
                in.read(bData);
                System.out.println("In Data"+in.toString());
                String st=new String (bData);

                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

                System.out.println("Response from server"+responseEntity);
                XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
                xr.parse(retrieveInputStream(responseEntity));
```

Comment: I'd guess that the garbage s not actually sent via HTTP but that you're doing something wrong when reading it (such as ignoring the return value of the `read()` call, for example). Show us the code used to read that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I expected. In this code:

```
byte[] bData = new byte[1024];
in.read(bData);
System.out.println("In Data"+in.toString());
String st=new String (bData);
```

You read some text and then convert the **whole `byte[]`** into a `String`, even if you didn't fill the whole `byte[]` with the `read`-call. Also, you ignore if there is any more data (i.e. if your content is more than 1024 bytes).

The simplest solution to this is to use an `InputSource` with the `InputStream` it self directly:

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(in));
```

The SAX parser already knows how to handle an `InputStream` and does all of that for you. There no need to re-implement that behaviour.

If you **absolutely** must read the whole response in memory, then you'd need to use code like this (but I wouldn't encourage this):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read=in.read(buf))!=-1) {
  baos.write(buf, 0, read);
}
byte[] output = baos.toByteArray();
```

Also note that converting this to a `String` is non-trivial, as the XML could have any encoding and you'd need to detect the correct one to correctly convert the `byte[]` to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

you must get how much bytes you have read, and then truncate with this value.

Also you can get `Content-Length` Header and use it to determine the length of body

Comment: im fetching data from mysql. so the length cannot be fixed... please suggest the option