# how to remove garbage value comin as a special characters with string in android

Tags: android, unicode, special-characters

in android when i am getting response from the server it's giving garbage values attaches with the string

100
66
ÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀÀ

i applied method .replace("À","");
but this is not working
should i use Unicode for that particular special character and if yes how to use that method..
Please suggest

Comment: I guess you have the exact same problem as [was discussed in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536785/garbage-value-in-http-response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all non-ascii chars from the string http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/java-remove-non-ascii-characters-how-to/

Comment: The correct solution would be not to get the wrong characters in the first place, as they are almost certainly the result of wrongly reading some data (see the question I linked to above).